# Commiting offsets despite throwing errors

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, error-handling, nestjs

I have a hybrid application using `connectMicroservice` to connect a Kafka microservice

```
  const application = await NestFactory.create(appModule)

  application.connectMicroservice(
    { transport: Transport.KAFKA, { client: { clientId: 'id', brokers: ['broker:123'] } } },
    { inheritAppConfig: true }
  )

  await application.startAllMicroservices()
  await application.listen(3000)
```

Somewhere in the business logic I throw an error for invalid messages which is only used for logging.

```
throw new RpcException('')
```

I log using a global exception handler. (But the issue occurs without a custom exception handler).

```
@Catch()
export class GlobalExceptionFilter implements RpcExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: RpcException, host: ArgumentsHost): Observable<any> {
    const data = host.switchToRpc().getData()
    console.log(data)
    return throwError(() => exception.getError())
  }
}
```

I want to *commit* this failed message to process the following messages, but regardless of the options I pass to the microservice, the message is never committed and the application retries to process this invalid message which blocks all other messages. I have tried different `client` configurations to no avail

```
retry: { retries: 1 }
```

I see the following error;

```
Error: ERROR [Runner] Error when calling eachMessage
```

I tried different [option](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/kafka#options) configurations for `run`, but nothing seems to have any effect. I also tried to define a custom function for `eachMessage`, but it doesn't get triggered.

I was considering manually committing the offset by defining a client, but the nestjs documentation appears to be [lacking a little](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/kafka#client) here as I struggle to get `ClientsModule.register` to work alongside with `application.connectMicroservice`.

Either I get issues about an application already running on the defined port, or the application doesn't appear to listen to the topic...